# AttributeError: 'DevicesTable' object has no attribute '_columns'"

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a class that inherits from the Table class as follows:

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, Integer, MetaData, String, Table, Text

class DevicesTable(Table):
    _name = 'devices'
    def __init__(self):
        Table.__init__(self, self._name,
            MetaData(schema=os.environ["DB_SCHEMA"]),
            Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
            Column('timezone', Text)
        )
```

and how I'm instantiating them:

```
# metadata_obj = sqlalchemy.MetaData(schema=os.environ["DB_SCHEMA"])
# table = Table(table_name, metadata_obj,
#             MetaData(schema=os.environ["DB_SCHEMA"]),
#             Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
#             Column('timezone', Text)
#         )
table = DevicesTable()
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DevicesTable' object has no attribute '_columns'"
```

My understanding is that the DevicesTable class should have all the attributes of the Table class. If I substitute the normal Table instantiation with the same columns in place of the DevicesTable instantiation it works fine, but maybe I'm just missing something. I am using python 3.8 and sqlalchemy 2.0.4

Comment: I suspect you need to call the `Table.__new__` before `__init__`. What exactly are you trying to do with this class?  There may be better ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: I will use the same definition in many places so I would like to have a class that is a table but has the columns already defined so I can just import that class definition and instantiate it where I need to use it.

Comment: I think the closest thing I've found is: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#declarative-with-imperative-table-a-k-a-hybrid-declarative
but I'm still not sure why the Table class itself would not be extensible in the way shown in my original post

Comment: Do you want the final object to be an ORM entity or a `Table`?

Comment: I'll be honest I still don't fully understand the difference, I have working code that uses it in the manner of the commented code above so I supposed I'd like to use it in that way.